# Diferencias entre Maven y Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, grails, groovy

Estoy comenzando con Gradle y me preguntaba cuáles son las principales diferencias con Maven a la hora de iniciar un nuevo proyecto en groovy/grails.

Nota: La pregunta puede ser considerada como opinión y ser moderada, agradecería que me ayuden a comprender las diferencias.

Answer (score 7):

Podemos decir que Gradle aprendió de los errores de Maven, porque finalmente realiza muchas de las mismas tareas, tiene la misma finalidad, pero eliminaron la complejidad de Maven.

En vez de tener que usar tanto XML, usas un DSL sobre Groovy. La creación de tareas personalizadas es extremadamente simple, al igual que el manejo de multi-proyectos. Los scripts de Gradle son bastante más legibles que los de Maven.

Gradle ofrece un bootstrap para que puedas ponerlo dentro de tu distribución de fuentes (en tu repo de git, por ejemplo) para que otros devs puedan construir tu proyecto sin tener que instalar Gradle.

Gradle puede usar el cache local de Maven para las dependencias y no tener que volver a bajar un montonal de cosas.

Gradle tiene un *daemon* que ayuda a agilizar mucho el tiempo de construcción de proyectos porque es un proceso que ya está corriendo siempre y por tanto elimina el tiempo de arranque de la JVM.